# having mysql codeigniter with sub query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, having

how to add when having obtained its queries like this?
opbal having with the conditions and minus and plus its more than zero ?
if minus > nol show, and all opbal,minus, and plus > nol
if minus > nol show, and all opbal,minus, and plus > nol

```html
$filter_col="";
  if(isset($filters['warehouse'])){
   foreach ($filters['warehouse'] as $filter_whse) {
    
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$filter_whse.", ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS location_".$filter_whse.",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$filter_whse.", ih.total_value, 0 ) ) AS tot_val_location_".$filter_whse.",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$filter_whse." AND ih.doc_date < "."'".$filters['date_from']."'".", ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS opening_qty_".$filter_whse.",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$filter_whse." AND ih.doc_date >= "."'".$filters['date_from']."'"." AND ih.item_qty > 0, ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS plus_qty_".$filter_whse.",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$filter_whse." AND ih.doc_date >= "."'".$filters['date_from']."'"." AND ih.item_qty < 0, ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS minus_qty_".$filter_whse.",";

   }
  }else{
   $all_location= $this->location_model->get_site_location();

   foreach ($all_location as $row_all_location) {
    
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$row_all_location['location_id'].", ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS location_".$row_all_location['location_id'].",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$row_all_location['location_id'].", ih.total_value, 0 ) ) AS tot_val_location_".$row_all_location['location_id'].",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$row_all_location['location_id']." AND ih.doc_date < "."'".$filters['date_from']."'".", ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS opening_qty_".$row_all_location['location_id'].",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$row_all_location['location_id']." AND ih.doc_date >= "."'".$filters['date_from']."'"." AND ih.item_qty > 0, ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS plus_qty_".$row_all_location['location_id'].",";
    $filter_col.= "sum( if( iw.location_id = ".$row_all_location['location_id']." AND ih.doc_date >= "."'".$filters['date_from']."'"." AND ih.item_qty < 0, ih.item_qty, 0 ) ) AS minus_qty_".$row_all_location['location_id'].",";

   }
  }

  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("v_itemhistory");
  // $this->db->where('doc_date >= ',$filters['date_from']);
  $this->db->where('doc_date <= ',$filters['date_to']);

  $sub_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

  $this->db->select("i.item_id, i.item_code, i.item_name,".$filter_col." , uom.uom, i.item_category_id, c.category_name");
  $this->db->from("t_inventory i");
  $this->db->join("t_uom uom","uom.uom = i.uom");
  $this->db->join("v_itembalance_warehouse iw","iw.item_id = i.item_id");
  $this->db->join("t_site_location s","s.location_id = iw.location_id");
  $this->db->join("t_inventory_category c","c.category_id = i.item_category_id");
  $this->db->join("($sub_query) as ih","ih.item_id = i.item_id and ih.whse_id = iw.location_id","left");
  if(isset($filters['warehouse'])){
   $this->db->where_in("iw.location_id",$filters['warehouse']);
  }
  if(isset($filters['category'])){

   $this->db->where_in('c.category_id',$filters['category']);
  }
  (isset($filters['typing']))?$this->db->where('i.item_id',$filters['typing'] ):'';
  $this->db->group_by("`i`.`item_id`, `i`.`item_code`, `i`.`item_name`, `uom`.`uom`,  `i`.`item_category_id`");
  $this->db->order_by("i.item_category_id,i.item_id","asc");
```

Comment: Good luck. But I'm not wading through all that.

Comment: Sometimes when i'm encountering complicated queries like this. I used the normal query (select * from ....) from that i can understand more the logic of my query. Just Saying. Anyway the question's or the problem is not clear. Dump the $this->db->last_query() and show us the result.